# Django ошибка whitenoise Missing staticfiles manifest entry for

Tags: django, static

возникает ошибка доступа файлов шаблонов, на сколько я понял из логов

при Debug=True, сайт открывается нормально и нормально работает, но ошибка в логах всетаки присутствует.

На сервере не применяются файлы перевода.
collectstatic выполняется без ошибок

в гугл ничего не нашел и близко...

Логи:

```html
[23/Apr/2018 18:10:48] ERROR [django.request:135] Internal Server Error: /en/theatrical-chairs/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ghusto/PycharmProjects/kresla/prg-kresla-heroku/kresla/catalog/views.py", line 135, in categories
    return render(request, template_link, context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 30, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 68, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 105, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 102, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 117, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 162, in url
    return self._url(self.stored_name, name, force)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 141, in _url
    hashed_name = hashed_name_func(*args)
  File "/home/ghusto/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 432, in stored_name
    raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'favicon.ico'
[23/Apr/2018 18:10:48] ERROR [django.server:124] "GET /en/theatrical-chairs/ HTTP/1.1" 500 27
```

Файл setting.py

```html
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
"""
Django settings for kresla project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'd9b%*y(poajcq#1*d%ri5x2w#&!rsc(%aoyfe)x!dmp^qf=!!v'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost']

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'modeltranslation',

    'sorl.thumbnail',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',

    'django_cleanup',
    'rosetta',
    'mptt',
    
    'controlpanel',
    'catalog',
    
    'news',
    'articles',
            
]

MPTT_ADMIN_LEVEL_INDENT = 40

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',

]



ROOT_URLCONF = 'kresla.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

                'allmenus.context_processors.all_menus_load',
                'siteoptions.context_processors.home_page',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'kresla.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        ....
    }
    
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'

#languages list
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', 'Russian'),
    ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
    ('en', 'English'),
)

MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'ru'

# language system start
USE_I18N = True
PROJECT_DIR = BASE_DIR+'kresla'
# laguage fales location
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    'locale',
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'locale'),
)

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Kiev'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://example.com/media/", "http://media.example.com/"
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

THUMBNAIL_FORMAT = 'PNG'

#CONN_MAX_AGE = 0

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
       'default': {
           'toolbar':[
                ['Maximize','Source','Preview','-', 'Undo', 'Redo'],
                ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', ],
                ['Link', 'Unlink','-', 'SpecialChar',],
                [ 'Replace','ShowBlocks','-','Blockquote', ],
                [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'TextColor', 'BGColor','-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter','JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock','NumberedList', 'BulletedList','-', 'Outdent', 'Indent','Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
                
                
                ['Styles', 'Format','Font','FontSize','Image','Table','CreateDiv',],
                
            ],
           'height': 400,
           'width': 600,
           'removePlugins': 'stylesheetparser',
           'extraPlugins': 'codesnippet',
       },
    }
    
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'mysite.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers':['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'MYAPP': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас возникает ошибка в момент, когда пользователь обращается к статическим, файлам из за:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

У вас указанно, что:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
```

При обращении к статичному файлу, приложение ищет его в `STATICFILES_DIRS`, но не находит, потому что статика собрана в `STATIC_ROOT`, а это разные папки.

Что бы использовать статичные файлы, их необходимо из `STATIC_ROOT` перенести в другое место и указать данную папку в `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

В продашкн среде, при `DEBUG=False`, лучше обслуживать статику `nginx`'ом.

Answer (score 0):

On Django 4.2+:

```
STORAGES = {
    # ...
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage",
    },
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]